# Too many redirection CSS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I obtain error style.css:1 GET https://www.example.com/cs_CZ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Could be related to my htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

EDIT:
After @RavinderSingh13 changes I have error with permissions
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Have your htaccess file in following way, please do make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
##Placing rules for non-https URLs here to apply https on URLs.
##Fixes: Added NE flag in rules here.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

##Placing rules for non www URLs here to apply www on URLs.
##Fixes: Added NE flag in rules here.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

##Rules for files to block those urls.
##Fixes: Added L flag to the rules.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess/?$ - [F]

##Removed condition RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ="" here as its not required.
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/index.php [L]

##Rules for non public uris to handle here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(public)/.*$ /$1/index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Good answer Ravinder. I can see you fixed the last rule . It should work +1 .

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, I change my answer. It seems, that your version return error.